# UV problems While Importing Ripp models In to Blender

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor, filmic-blender

I am ripping models from a ps3 game, but the software I use extract the textures and models but no the UV maps, so I was wondering if some of you know how to fix this issue.

In the ripping process I get solid colors cause all the UV maps are a mess
[image]

I have been fixing the UV map a bit with the setting of project from view, but it does not work at all.

[image]

and If I unwrap the UV maps I get this result

[image]

I want to get like the form of the face so I can use the current textures I have to remake them or try to make them fit with the original one.

If you know a solucion I wold be glad to here it, TY so much to read!

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)